# SED for all values in key value pairs

Tags: linux, sed

How do I get the all values from a "key"="value" in a file.

Example: I have a text file as below:

"This is the file which contains,"key"="value",so extract value. This is the file which contains another value,"key"="value1",so extract value."

Comment: Maybe use grep `grep '"key"='`?

Comment: Sorry, but your text and example are not entirely clear. Please study the [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this help?

```
grep -oP '(?<=\"key\"=\")(.*?)(?=\")' file anotherfile
```

If you don't want filenames in output use `-h`